# Spreadsheet::Read and columns

Tags: perl

I'm trying to extract all the data in various columns of my spreadsheet using Perl's Spreadsheet::Read. For example, I want to extract all the data in the following columns:

```
A1 = 'NewRecordFlag'
B1 = 'AgencyName'
C1 = 'CredentialIdnt'
```

In the Spreadsheet::Read module I can extract all data from rows but how do I from columns?

In the following example, the code below is extracting data from row 6. So, how do I create an array of A1, B1, and C1?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use Data::Printer;
use Spreadsheet::Read qw(row rows);
use Spreadsheet::Read;



my $workbook = ReadData("test.xls");

my @row = row($workbook->[1], 6);
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this with the `Spreadsheet::BasicReadNamedCol` module

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;
use Spreadsheet::BasicReadNamedCol;

my $xlsFileName = 'test.xls';
my @columnHeadings = (
'AgencyName',
'eMail',
'PhysicalAddress1',
'PhysicalAddress2'
);

my $ss = new Spreadsheet::BasicReadNamedCol($xlsFileName) ||
die "Could not open '$xlsFileName': $!";
$ss->setColumns(@columnHeadings);

# Print each row of the spreadsheet in the order defined in
# the columnHeadings array
my $row = 0;
while (my $data = $ss->getNextRow())
{
$row++;
print join('|', $row, @$data), "\n";
}
```